# Why guards act differently than 'case - of' notation?

Tags: function, haskell, types, option-type

I was doing some haskell programming and had an error when using guards, when i changed guards to 'case of' the problem was gone, and i can't understan why exactly is that happening. I've made a a very simple example of the situation i was in:

```
data Point = Point Float Float deriving (Show)  
data Shape = Circle Point Float | Rectangle Point Point deriving (Show)

c1 :: Shape
c1 = Circle (Point 5 5 ) 12

--returns Just True if radius is bigger than 10, otherwise = Nothing
isBigger :: Shape -> Maybe Bool
isBigger (Circle _ x) 
         |x > 10 = Just True
         |otherwise = Nothing
```

Now, i've made these two functions (Apart from different notation they seem to do exactly the same to me):
first:

```
printStuff:: Shape -> String
printStuff s1
        |isBigger s1 == Just a = show a
        |isBigger s1 == Nothing = "Not bigger than 10"
```

and the second one:

```
printStuff2:: Shape -> String
printStuff2 s1 =
     case isBigger s1 of 
        Nothing -> "Not Bigger than 10"
        Just a -> show a
```

But, code with with function 'PrintStuff' won't run. Error:

Not in scope: ‘a’

However, second function runs and does its job. Whats the difference between  guards and case here?

Comment: `isBigger s1 == Just a` won't type check because you are attempting to deconstruct the result of `isBigger s1` in a boolean comparison. The following would be valid: `isJust $ isBigger s1 = show . fromJust $ isBigger s1`. As you can see the `case of` is much cleaner.

Comment: @recursion.ninja: If `a` was known at that point, it would type check (if it had the type `K` from `isBigger :: Shape -> Maybe K`). But that's not really a deconstruction either ^^.

Comment: Guards are like a series of conditionals, not patterns - your guard version is equivalent to `printStuff s1 = if isBigger s1 == Just a then show a else "Not bigger than 10"`.

Comment: It might help to point out that `==` is just a normal function (it is a function that happens to be part of a type class, but a function nonetheless) and guards just use any Haskell expression of type `Bool`. If you try to apply any function to a variable that isn't defined it won't define it, it will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

Guards use boolean expressions, whereas `case … of` uses pattern matching. So for `case`, the usual pattern match rules hold. So your second function is (almost) the same as:

```
printStuff2:: Shape -> String
printStuff2 s1 = helper (isBigger s1)
  where
    helper Nothing  = "Not Bigger than 10"
    helper (Just a) = show a
    --     ^^^^^^^
    --  pattern matching
```

Now, guards did not pattern match originally (that was introduced by an [extensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard)). They only take expressions of type `Bool`:

```
printStuff :: Shape -> String
printStuff s1 
  | bigger == Nothing = "Not Bigger than 10"
  | otherwise         = a
 where 
   bigger   = isBigger s1
   (Just a) = bigger
```

Note that the last binding can be dangerous if you forget to check whether `bigger` is actually `Just something`. However, with PatternGuards, you can use

```
printStuff :: Shape -> String
printStuff s1 
  | Just a <- isBigger s1 = show a
  | otherwise             = "Not Bigger than 10"
```

That being said, this is a job for [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe):

```
printStuff :: Shape -> String
printStuff s1 = maybe "Not Bigger than 10" show (isBigger s1)
```

Comment: I think i understood the part about pattern matching and why guards didn't work. However, you lart maybe statement blew my mind. Maybe im not advanced enough yet to understand that. I thought Maybe type constructor takes ONE type and resulting type may be: Maybe Int, Maybe String, etc... I can't see what maybe type constructor does when given  "Not Bigger than 10" show (isBigger s1)"

Comment: @EasternDude `Maybe` is a type; `maybe` is a function, with type `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`. If the third argument is `Nothing` it returns the first argument, otherwise it applies the second argument to the value "inside" the `Maybe`.

Comment: oh, its maybe not Maybe, now it makes sense :D thanks for pointing the obvious :D didin't come across this function before, yet

Comment: @EasternDude: That's why I've added a link to the documentation ^^. As an exercise, there is a function called `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`. Try to figure out what it does just by looking at its type.